# How to cache data from repository call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, data-access-layer, dottrace

I am working in a multi-layered web application that has ASP.NET MVC as its front-end client. A particular page of this web application is taking a very long time to load. Around 30 seconds.

I downloaded [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and ran it on my application (following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxOWaRkFSMM)). I found out that the reason my application is slow.

It turns out it is because one particular method that I have does a load of work (takes time), and that same method gets called a total of 4 times.

Here is a screenshot from dotTrace showing the above:

[image: dotTrace screenshot]

The method in question is `GetTasks()`. So in order to improve the speed of the web application I want to **cache the data returned from `GetTasks()`** for each request.

If my thinking is correct, this would really improve on the speed issues I am having.

My question is, how can I achieve this? I have never done such a thing before. For each new request, how can I cache the data returned from `GetTasks()`, and use that for all subsequent calls to `GetTasks()`.

Comment: Do your tasks have some sort of unique identifier you can recognize them by?

Comment: Yeah, they have an Id?

Comment: Caching *can* often help considerably.  One thing to also check is what's actually going across the wire.  Are the queries efficient?  I found that many of my queries where all that efficient initially and needed some tweaking (indexes) to improve things.

Comment: @itsmatt thanks yep, that is what I'll do next. First need to get the caching working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most popsular solution is to cache results. I can shouw you my solution.
First of all install Nuget package: [LazyCache](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LazyCache/)
Then you can use wrapper that I've created wrapper: [code](http://pastebin.com/fj0xr7Ut). You can extract and interface or whatever.

Then you can use it like this:

```
private readonly CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(); 
          // or injected via ctor

public IEnumerable<Task> GetTasks()
{
    return this.cacheManager.Get("Tasks", ctx => this.taskRepository.GetAll());
}

public void AddTask(Task task)
{
    this.taskRepository.Create(task);
    /// other code

    // we need to tell the cache that it should get fresh collectiion
    this.cacheManager.Signal("Tasks"); 
}
```

Comment: I did [something similar](http://pastebin.com/b4v5TiYW) following an article from Microsoft, but not getting any performance improvement. I'm guessing I'm messing it up somewhere!

Comment: Without the code for CacheManager this answer seems a little incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [Cache Aside pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside)?

You can implement it easily using [LazyCache](https://github.com/alastairtree/lazycache)

```
//probably in my constructor (or use dependency injection)
this.cache = new CachingService()

public List<MyTasks> GetTasks() 
{
    return cache.GetOrAdd<List<MyTasks>>("get-tasks", () = > {
        //go and get the tasks here.
    });
}
```

For more information see https://alastaircrabtree.com/the-easy-way-to-add-caching-to-net-application-and-make-it-faster-is-called-lazycache/